# no-nested-ternary on a nested and complicated array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a complicated array of objects and I want to change a property that deeply nested in the array.

I did the following function and it is work, but the problem is that the eslint throw me an error because there is a nested ternery to check if i am on the currect place in an array:

```js
toggleSwitchDetector(state: Array<IOpticalHeadUnit>, { payload }: any) {
            return [
                ...state.map((opticalHeadUnit) =>
                    opticalHeadUnit.name === payload.opticalHeadUnitName
                        ? {
                            ...opticalHeadUnit,
                            detectors: [
                                ...opticalHeadUnit.detectors.map(
                                    (detector, index) => ({
                                        ...detector,
                                        status: {
                                            ...detector.status,
                                            value: //Nested ternery. Bad practice.
                                                index === payload.index
                                                    ? detector.status
                                                        .value === 0
                                                        ? 1
                                                        : 0
                                                    : detector.status.value,
                                        },
                                    }),
                                ),
                            ],
                          }
                        : opticalHeadUnit,
                ),
            ];
        }
```

is there a simpler way to approach the modification of the deeply nested property?

EDIT:

the code after I modified it with the answers:

```js
const getDetectorStatusValue=(index:number,payload:number,detector:IDetector)=>{
    if(index === payload)
    {
        if(detector.status.value===0)
            return 1
        return 0
    }
    return detector.status.value
    
        
}

toggleSwitchDetector(state: Array<IOpticalHeadUnit>, { payload }: any) {
            return state.map((opticalHeadUnit) =>
                opticalHeadUnit.name === payload.opticalHeadUnitName
                    ? {
                        ...opticalHeadUnit,
                        detectors: [
                            ...opticalHeadUnit.detectors.map(
                                (detector,index) => ({
                                    ...detector,
                                    status: {
                                        ...detector.status,
                                        value:getDetectorStatusValue(index,payload.index,detector)
                                    },
                                }),
                            ),
                        ],
                          }
                    : opticalHeadUnit,
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
toggleSwitchDetector(state: Array<IOpticalHeadUnit>, { payload }: any) {
    return state.map((opticalHeadUnit) => getState(payload, opticalHeadUnit)
}

getStatus(payload, detector) {
  return {
    ...detector.status,
    value: //Nested ternery. Bad practice.
        index === payload.index
            ? detector.status
                .value === 0
                ? 1
                : 0
            : detector.status.value,
  };
}

getDetectors(payload, opticalHeadUnit) {
  return opticalHeadUnit.detectors.map(
        (detector, index) => ({
            ...detector,
            status: getStatus(payload, detector),
        }),
    );
}

getState(payload, opticalHeadUnit) {
    opticalHeadUnit.name === payload.opticalHeadUnitName
        ? {
            ...opticalHeadUnit,
            detectors: getDetectors(payload, opticalHeadUnit);
          }
        : opticalHeadUnit,
}
```

you don't need [...array], replace it with array

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the nested ternary operator, you could write slightly more code but it will be more readable.
You can check if `index === payload.index` with a simple `if statement` and only in that case go deep in your object to eventually check `detector.status.value === 0 ? 1 : 0`

Otherwise just return `detector` as is;

```js
...opticalHeadUnit.detectors.map(
  (detector, index) => ({
    if (index === payload.index) {
      return {
        ...detector,
        status: {
          ...detector.status,
          value: detector.status.value === 0 ? 1 : 0
        },
      }
    } else {
      return detector;
    }
  }),
),
```